# Исключение подобных выражений регулярными выражениями

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Имеется следующий текст:

```
Running postupdate SQL scripts...
Executing script: Init!Checks.SQL
Выключен контроль целостности данных базы. Включить!
Msg 50000, Level 1, State 16, Line 2, Procedure '', Server 'dbs'
Выключено автоматическое создание статистик. Включить!
Msg 50000, Level 1, State 16, Line 2, Procedure '', Server 'dbs'
Выключен режим SNAPSHOT. Включить!
Msg 50000, Level 1, State 16, Line 2, Procedure '', Server 'dbs'
Error messages: 3
Queries count 15

Executing script: Common_MESSAGE.SQL
Error messages: 0
Queries count 43

Executing script: Common_TYPEDEF.SQL
Error messages: 0
Queries count 5

Executing script: Init_CommonRights.SQL
Error messages: 0
Queries count 32
Executing script: Init!Checks.SQL
Выключен контроль целостности данных базы. Включить!
Msg 50000, Level 1, State 16, Line 2, Procedure '', Server 'dbs'
Выключено автоматическое создание статистик. Включить!
Msg 50000, Level 1, State 16, Line 2, Procedure '', Server 'dbs'
Выключен режим SNAPSHOT. Включить!
Msg 50000, Level 1, State 16, Line 2, Procedure '', Server 'dbs'
Error messages: 3
```

Надо выделить фрагменты между `Executing script:` и `Error messages: [1-9]`. Если встречен `Error messages: 0`, то фрагмент выделять не нужно.

Регулярки я проверяю на сервисе [RegExr](http://regexr.com/).

Написал следующую: `(Executing script:)[\w\W]*?(Error messages: [1-9])`. Но она не обрабатывает вышеописанную ситуацию с `Error messages: 0`. Вот более наглядно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока не могу сообразить, как мне исключить выделенные фрагменты. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В таких случаях необходимо использовать "жадный" "умеренный" квантификатор (англ. "tempered greedy token"):

```
(?s)Executing script:(?:(?!Executing script:).)*?Error messages: [1-9]
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/NTbDvI/1). Тут точка находит любой символ кроме такого, который является началом подстроки `Executing script:`.

Здесь `(?s)` является строковой версией опции `RegexOptions.Singleline`, благодаря которой `.` также находит знаки перехода на новую строку (LF).

Comment: Спасибо. Я честно прочитал на MSDN про элементы регулярных выражений, но "собрать до кучи" информацию не смог. После Вашего объяснения человеческим языком формулировки MSDN стали более понятными.На практике еще не попробовал - пока нет доступа к компу.

Comment: @Артур Честно говоря, я не всё описание привёл. Если что непонятно, задайте вопрос в комментарии, я обновлю ответ.

Comment: Я завтра попробую подебажить - так будет полезнее, чтобы понять, а не просто запомнить. Если вопросы остануться - обязательно задам. Еще раз большое спасибо.

Comment: все отработало. Вроде пока все понятно. Спасибо.