# отрицание в regex

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

этим патерном `\bif\((.+)\)\{([\s\S]+?)}` я выбираю все блоки if
http://joxi.ru/8AnWw7VcqgpKOr
как мне выделить все кроме этих блоков. грубо говоря инвертировать патерн

проверяю в сервисе https://regexr.com/

Comment: Можно так - `s.split(/\bif\(.+\)\{[\s\S]+?}/)`. Пользуйтесь http://regex101.com, там всё гораздо понятнее.

Comment: Проверяете в сервисе, а делитесь скриншотом... Там же есть share?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/DW3W3I/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Регулярные выражения обычно используются для *нахождения* текста. Например, если нужно найти все цифры, можно использовать `/\d+/g`. Если нужно найти все символы, отличные от цифр, можно пользоваться "инвертированным" классом `\D`, `/\D+/g`. Для регулярных выражений, содержащих *последовательности* шаблонов, не существует такого "конструкта", который бы находил текст, отличный от такой последовательности (есть один такой, Lucene, но он, скорее, исключение, да и более похож на wildcard-шаблоны). Близко по значению подходит [*"жадный" "умеренный" квантификатор*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667821/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8/668076#668076) (tempered greedy token, `/(?:(?!ШАБЛОН)[\s\S])+/g`), но он, на самом деле, находит последовательность символов, которые не являются начальным пунктом ШАБЛОНа.

Для "отрицания" или "инвертирования" данного шаблона достаточно разбить строку с его помощью, предварительно заменив захватывающие подмаски незахватываемыми (чтобы избежать добавления захваченных подстрок в получаемый массив):

```js
var s = "[prop_code_4] - это r('необычный', 'необыкновенный', 'особенный', 'феноменальный', 'незаурядный', 'особый', 'оригинальный', 'курьезный', 'непривычный', 'непростой', 'удивительный') гаджет, r('предназначенный', 'созданный', 'который создан') для погружения в мир r('виртуальной', 'дополненной', 'дополнительной') \r\nif( [prop_code_2] == 'Красный' ){\r\nСегодня для погружения в мир r('виртуальной', 'дополненной') r('реальности', 'действительности') r('достаточно', 'стоит только', 'необходимо') иметь при себе смартфон плюс [prop_code_4]. r('Обладая', 'Владея') всем этим, дело остается за малым, всего-то найти r('необходимый', 'нужный', 'подходящий') медиа-контент это могут быть как r('приложения, игры', 'игры, приложения'), так и r('видеоролики', 'видео', 'видеозаписи')\r\n}\r\n\r\n[prop_code_4] - это r('необычный', 'необыкновенный', 'особенный', 'феноменальный', 'незаурядный', 'особый', 'оригинальный', 'курьезный', 'непривычный', 'непростой', 'удивительный') гаджет, r('предназначенный', 'созданный', 'который создан') для погружения в мир r('виртуальной', 'дополненной', 'дополнительной') \r\nif( [prop_code_2] == 'Красный' ){\r\nСегодня для погружения в мир r('виртуальной', 'дополненной') r('реальности', 'действительности') r('достаточно', 'стоит только', 'необходимо') иметь при себе смартфон плюс [prop_code_4]. r('Обладая', 'Владея') всем этим, дело остается за малым, всего-то найти r('необходимый', 'нужный', 'подходящий') медиа-контент это могут быть как r('приложения, игры', 'игры, приложения'), так и r('видеоролики', 'видео', 'видеозаписи')\r\n}";
var result = s.split(/\bif\(.+\)\{[\s\S]+?}/);
console.log(result.join("")); // если нужна строка
console.log(result.filter(Boolean)); // если нужен массив
```

`.filter(Boolean)` удалит пустые элементы массива.